# sparql --order by returning empty response

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am new to SPARQL and trying a simple query which has ORDER BY at the end, the query i working fine but the moment I add ORDER BY at the end, I get empty response. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Works fine:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpediaowl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>



SELECT * WHERE 
{  
  {?private dbpediaowl:city dbpedia:Los_Angeles} UNION {?private dbpprop:location     dbpedia:Los_Angeles}

  ?private dbpprop:established ?yr.
  bind(year(now())-?yr as ?age).
  FILTER (?age > 100). }
```

Same query with ORDER BY returns empty response:

```
  SELECT * WHERE 
  {  
    {?private dbpediaowl:city dbpedia:Los_Angeles} UNION {?private dbpprop:location dbpedia:Los_Angeles}

   ?private dbpprop:established ?yr.
   bind(year(now())-?yr as ?age).
   FILTER (?age > 100) . } 
    ORDER BY ?age
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: When I run the second query you posted on the DBpedia public endpoint (after changing `dbpediaowl` to `dbpedia-owl`, to match their predefined prefixes), I don't get an empty response;  I get "Wrong arguments for datetime arithmetic, can not subtract value of type 211 (DATETIME) from value type 189 (INTEGER)."  How are you running your query, and what do you mean by an empty response?

Comment: Can you clarify how you're running your query?  As I explained in my answer, when I run this query, I don't get an empty response, I actually get an error.  If you can provide more code for how you're actually running this query, perhaps some other answer can be determined.

Answer (score 3):

You can try out SPARQL queries using the [public DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).  In trying to recreate your query, I was successful up through the following query:

```
select * where {  
  {
    ?private dbpedia-owl:city dbpedia:Los_Angeles
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?private dbpprop:location dbpedia:Los_Angeles
  }
  ?private dbpprop:established ?year.
  bind(year(now())-?year as ?age).
  filter (?age > 100).
} 
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20%2a%20where%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?private%20dbpedia-owl%3acity%20dbpedia%3aLos_Angeles%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?private%20dbpprop%3alocation%20dbpedia%3aLos_Angeles%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20?private%20dbpprop%3aestablished%20?year.%0D%0A%20%20bind%28year%28now%28%29%29-?year%20as%20?age%29.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28?age%20%3E%20100%29.%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Notice that some of the results in that query have some values that you might not have expected.  e.g.,

```
private                                             year                                        age
...                                                 ...                                         ...
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard-Westlake_School "''Harvard School for Boys: 1900"@en        2013
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard-Westlake_School "Fully Merged as Harvard-Westlake: 1991"@en 2013
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harvard-Westlake_School "Westlake School for Girls: 1904''"@en      2013
```

Now, when I add the `order by ?age` to the query, I get a rather descriptive error message back, which begins with:

> Virtuoso 22003 Error SR087: Wrong arguments for datetime arithmetic, can not subtract value of type 211 (DATETIME) from value type 189 (INTEGER).

After some digging into datatypes of some of these values, it looks like something very strange is happening with the datatype of `now()` (but it looks like *your* query is using is correctly).  Look at this query:

```
select ?now ?nowtype where { 
  values ?value { <urn:ex:value> } # only here so that there are non-bind variables
  bind( now() as ?now )
  bind( datatype(now()) as ?nowtype )
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?now%20?nowtype%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20values%20?value%20%7B%20%3Curn%3aex%3avalue%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20bind%28%20now%28%29%20as%20?now%20%29%0D%0A%20%20bind%28%20datatype%28now%28%29%29%20as%20?nowtype%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The results are:

```
now                               nowtype
2013-09-13T21:11:11.000005+02:00  2013-09-13T21:11:11.000005+02:00
```

It looks like the datatype of the literal returned by `now()` is the same as the time! [`now`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-now) is supposed to return a `xsd:dateTime` though!  For comparison, the same query, run with Jena's ARQ, returns:

```
now                                                                          nowtype
"2013-09-13T15:24:10.908-04:00"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>
```

There is something strange going on here, and I haven't been able to construct a working query yet.  However, I'd advise you to get in touch with their [mailing list](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Support) and ask them directly, because this *doesn't* look like a problem in your SPARQL.

### Additional Strange Results

This query is bizarre, in that while all the values for `theYear` that it produces are indeed at least 100 years ago, the ages make no sense at all.

```
select ?private ?theYear ?age where { 
  values ?location { dbpedia-owl:city dbpprop:location } 
  ?private ?location dbpedia:Los_Angeles ;
           dbpprop:established ?year .
  bind( if( datatype(?year) = xsd:int, xsd:integer(?year), year(now()) ) as ?theYear )
  bind( year(now()) - ?theYear as ?age )
  filter( ?age > xsd:integer(100) )
}
order by ?age
```

[results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?private%20?theYear%20?age%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20values%20?location%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3acity%20dbpprop%3alocation%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20?private%20?location%20dbpedia%3aLos_Angeles%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpprop%3aestablished%20?year%20.%0D%0A%20%20bind%28%20if%28%20datatype%28?year%29%20=%20xsd%3aint,%20xsd%3ainteger%28?year%29,%20year%28now%28%29%29%20%29%20as%20?theYear%20%29%0D%0A%20%20bind%28%20year%28now%28%29%29%20-%20?theYear%20as%20?age%20%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20?age%20%3E%20xsd%3ainteger%28100%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20?age&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

I tried doing a bunch of datatype casting to make sure that the values being produced were of appropriate datatypes, and ended up with this query:

```
select * where { 
  values ?location { dbpedia-owl:city dbpprop:location } 
  ?private ?location dbpedia:Los_Angeles ;
           dbpprop:established ?established .

  bind( xsd:int(year(now())) as ?nowYear )
  bind( if( datatype(?established) = xsd:dateTime || datatype(?established) = xsd:date, 
            year(xsd:dateTime(?established)),
            if( datatype(?established) = xsd:integer || datatype(?established) = xsd:int,
                xsd:int(?established),
                ?nowYear ) )
        as ?year )
  bind( ?nowYear - ?year as ?age )
}
```

[results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20%2a%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20values%20?location%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3acity%20dbpprop%3alocation%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20?private%20?location%20dbpedia%3aLos_Angeles%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpprop%3aestablished%20?established%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20bind%28%20xsd%3aint%28year%28now%28%29%29%29%20as%20?nowYear%20%29%0D%0A%20%20bind%28%20if%28%20datatype%28?established%29%20=%20xsd%3adateTime%20%7C%7C%20datatype%28?established%29%20=%20xsd%3adate,%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20year%28xsd%3adateTime%28?established%29%29,%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%28%20datatype%28?established%29%20=%20xsd%3ainteger%20%7C%7C%20datatype%28?established%29%20=%20xsd%3aint,%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xsd%3aint%28?established%29,%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?nowYear%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20as%20?year%20%29%0D%0A%20%20bind%28%20?nowYear%20-%20?year%20as%20?age%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Its results show that everything is being computed correctly, but if we add a `filter( ?age > 100 )` to it, we get [these results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20%2a%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20values%20?location%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3acity%20dbpprop%3alocation%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20?private%20?location%20dbpedia%3aLos_Angeles%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpprop%3aestablished%20?established%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20bind%28%20xsd%3aint%28year%28now%28%29%29%29%20as%20?nowYear%20%29%0D%0A%20%20bind%28%20if%28%20datatype%28?established%29%20=%20xsd%3adateTime%20%7C%7C%20datatype%28?established%29%20=%20xsd%3adate,%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20year%28xsd%3adateTime%28?established%29%29,%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%28%20datatype%28?established%29%20=%20xsd%3ainteger%20%7C%7C%20datatype%28?established%29%20=%20xsd%3aint,%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xsd%3aint%28?established%29,%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?nowYear%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20as%20?year%20%29%0D%0A%20%20bind%28%20?nowYear%20-%20?year%20as%20?age%20%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20?age%20%3E%20100%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on) wherein plenty of the ages are less than 100, and while all of the `year` values indicate that we're getting the right entries, the `age` values are simply incorrect. E.g.,

```
private http://dbpedia.org/resource/UCLA_Graduate_School_of_Education_and_Information_Studies
now     2013
then    1881
age     66
```

is just plain wrong.

Comment: yea thanks, but I am trying to order my query results in ascending order, so I get an error as Empty response when I combine bind with ORDER BY

Comment: This raises some questions about your question, so I've commented on it above (rather than here on my answer).